# sIFR 3 issue (IE) with BlockUI and UpdatePanel

Tags: updatepanel, sifr, blockui

I am experience an issue using sIFR 3, jQuery BlockUI and an UpdatePanel where the page refreshes and the SIFR font disappears.

In the Javascript file I use to handle the blocking and unblocking of the UI, I detect the partial postback and unblock the UI:

prm.add_endRequest(function() {
$.unblockUI(); });

If I re-run sIFR.replace() in this code block the font sIFR font is rendered, but # characters are replacing my page title (in the top of the browser window/tab). This seems to only happen in IE (go figure.) Each time I refresh the page using the LinkButton an extra # character is added, so my page title ends up looking like "#########". Any idea why this is happening?

Is there a specific sIFR.update() function I should be running instead?  If I execute sIFR.redraw() or sIFR() I get javascript run time errors.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by a bug in IE:

> This is a very peculiar bug in IE where for each Flash movie in the page the fragment identifier part of the URI (#foo) is repeated in the document title. It has been reported by Macromedia that this bug can be fixed by updating the VBScript engine the browser uses. However, for those users who still have the wrong engine sIFR contains a workaround.
>   http://wiki.novemberborn.net/sifr/Fragment+Identifier+Bug

sIFR 3 has a workaround but it doesn't kick in unless the page is loaded with a fragment identifier (`window.location.hash != ""`). In your case, I assume the page is loaded without the identifier, then you add one, and then you re-run replacements, reinvoking the bug.

You can patch r436 by opening (the compressed version of) `sifr.js` and replacing `this.fix=c.ua.ieWin&&window.location.hash!=""` by `this.fix=c.ua.ieWin`.